# JQuery and MVC Session Time Out not redirecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've a MVC application which uses $.ajax to fetch data from Controller.

Unfortunately, when session time out occurs the page doesn't get redirected to Login page. Could someone help with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with the ajax respond that you get when the session timed out?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom [Authorize] attribute which would return JSON instead of throwing a 401 exception in case of unauthorized access which would allow client scripts to handle the scenario gracefully:

```
AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new 
                { 
                    // put whatever data you want which will be sent
                    // to the client
                    message = "sorry, but you were logged out" 

                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

In ajax You could do this :

```
$.get('@Url.Action("SomeAction")', function (result) {
    if (result.message) {
        alert(result.message);
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        // do whatever you were doing before with the results
    }
});
```

Comment: The first line in the code sample is missing a left square bracket and should be:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]

Answer (score 0):

if by default the page suppose to redirect you can try to catch the specific timeout/authentication error and based on this error redirect from client to login controller

here an example taken from this article

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "/yourservlet",
  data: { },
  complete: function(xmlHttp) {
     if(xmlHttp.status==401)
      {
    // redirect to login page

     }
  }
});
```